# Expand $\cos(x)$ in odd Fourier series.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> Expand $\cos(x)$ in sinus-series in the interval $(0,\pi/2)$ and use
>   the result to calculate $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2}.$$

Since we only need the odd terms in the Fourier expansion, we know that $a_n=0$, so we only need $b_n$ in order to find the sine expansion.

In my book, there is a chapter on *"Fourier series on intervals"*, and there they state that:

---

*If $f$ is a piecewise smooth function on $[0,l]$, then the Fourier sine expansion is given by*

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n\sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{l}\right),\tag{1}$$

where

$$b_n=\frac{2}{l}\int\limits_{0}^{l}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{\pi n x}{l}\right).\tag{2}$$

---

So we should be able to use only $(1)$ and $(2)$ with $l=\pi/2$ to solve this problem. So

\begin{align}
b_n=\frac{4}{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\sin(2nx)dx = \frac{4(\sin(\pi n)-2n)}{\pi(1-4n^2)}\tag{3}.
\end{align}

This gives

$$\cos(x)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{4n^2-1}\sin(2nx), \quad \forall \ n\in\mathbb{N}\tag{4}$$

2 questions remain:

1. I used wolfram alpha to calculate the integral in $(3)$. What methods do I use to do this? Repeated integration by parts and solve for the integral?
2. How do I calculate the desired sum?

Comment: The function to expand is probably not the regular $\cos$. Instead, consider the function that coincides with $\cos$ on $(0, \frac \pi 2)$, that is odd and is $\pi$ periodic.

Comment: But they explicitly state that I'm to expand $\cos(x)$. So I am pretty convinced that $\cos(x)$ is the regular cos that is to be expanded. I might have misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As posted by the OP, two steps remain:

1. Perform the integral:

$$
b_n=\frac{4}{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\sin(2nx)dx \\
= \frac{1}{i \pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}e^{ix(1+2n)}- e^{ix(1-2n)}+e^{-ix(1-2n)}-e^{-ix(1+2n)}dx \\
= \frac{1}{i \pi} \left(\frac{e^{ix(1+2n)}}{i(1+2n)}|_{0}^{\pi/2} - \frac{e^{ix(1-2n)}}{i(1-2n)}|_{0}^{\pi/2} + \frac{e^{-ix(1-2n)}}{-i(1-2n)}|_{0}^{\pi/2} -\frac{e^{-ix(1+2n)}}{-i(1+2n)}|_{0}^{\pi/2} \right)\\
= \frac{1}{i \pi} \left(\frac{i(-1)^n - 1}{i(1+2n)} - \frac{i(-1)^n - 1}{i(1-2n)} + \frac{-i(-1)^n - 1}{-i(1-2n)} - \frac{-i(-1)^n - 1}{-i(1+2n)} \right)\\
= \frac{1}{- \pi (1 - 4 n^2)} \left( -4n(i(-1)^n - 1) - 4n (-i(-1)^n - 1)  \right)\\
= \frac{-8n}{\pi(1-4n^2)} \\
= \frac{4(\sin(\pi n)-2n)}{\pi(1-4n^2)}
$$
where the last step only indicates the "desired" solution by WolframAlpha, where anyway $\sin(\pi n) = 0$ .

2 Calculating the desired sum.

From OP's last result,
$$
\cos(x)=\frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{4n^2-1}\sin(2nx),
$$
 multiply this formula with $\cos(x) $ and integrate, using the integral which was just derived:

$$
\frac{\pi}{4} = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^2(x) dx = \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{4n^2 -1} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x)\cdot\sin(2nx) dx = \\
\frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{4n^2 -1} \cdot \frac{2 n}{4n^2 -1}\\ 
= \frac{16}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(4n^2 -1)^2}  
$$
so finally

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{(4n^2 -1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{64} 
$$

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f(x) = \cos(x) \cdot {\rm{sign}}(x)$ in the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$. This function is identical to $\cos(x)$ in the interval $(0, \pi/2)$ so the expansion will be correct in that interval.

You want $f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m \sin(mx)$.

Integrating with $\sin(nx)$ gives

$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin( n x)\sin(nx)dx = \pi
$$
$$
 \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin( m x)\sin(nx)dx = 0 \quad (m\ne n)
$$
and

$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos(x)\cdot {\rm{sign}}(x) \cdot \sin(nx)dx = 2 \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)\cdot \sin(nx)dx =  2 \frac{n (1+\cos(\pi n))}{n^2 - 1} \tag{*}
$$

So you have 
$$
\cos(x) = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n (1+\cos(\pi n))}{n^2 - 1} \sin(nx)
$$
where the coefficients are nonzero for even n.

Substituting $n$  with $2 m$ gives
$$
\cos(x) = \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m}{4m^2 -1} \sin(2 m x)
$$

No use the integral in (*) again: multiply the last formula with $\cos(x) $ and integrate:

$$
\frac{\pi}{2} = \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\cos^2(x) dx = \frac{8}{\pi} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m}{4m^2 -1} \int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\cos(x)\cdot\sin(2mx) dx = \frac{32}{\pi} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m^2}{(4m^2 -1)^2} 
$$
so finally

$$
\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{m^2}{(4m^2 -1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{64} 
$$

Comment: Thanks for a nice solution and I'll give you an upvote. However this answer fails to provide an answer that aids in helping me to understand my mistake. I'd rather learn where I went wrong in my own attempt then see a customized soluton that would only work for this particular problem. For example, I've never had to deal with the $sgn(x)$ function and there is not a single example in the book where they use a method like this to solve a similar problem. This problem is solveable using standard given formulae and I want to know why it did not work this time.

Comment: If you want it without that symmetry condition, you would have to set $\cos(x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty b_m \sin(2mx)$ which we know (in hindsight) from the solution above. It is not clear to me a priori that the odd terms $\sin((2m+1)x)$ should not be present in the series at all  - do you have an argument? Then, you can integrate $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(2mx) \sin(2nx) dx = 0$ for $m \ne n$  and everything works as above. (continued)

Comment: (continued) The point is that in general,  $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin(mx) \sin(nx) dx $ is not zero and therefore the calculation of the coefficients does not work straightforward if you cannot exclude the odd values of m right from the start.

Comment: I've been working on this problem a bit further now, I'll edit the answer and show you what I mean by applying the formulas straight on. Stand by.

Comment: Please see my edit now Andreas. Thanks for the time and effort you put in, I apreciate it. Oh and the answer $\pi^2/64$ is indeed correct.

Comment: From what you quoted from your textbook, indeed we are looking at the Fourier Half Range sine series. When inserting $l = \pi/2$  this actually works, since this gives $\int\limits_{-0}^{\pi/2}\sin( 2 m x)\sin(2 nx)dx = 0 \quad (m\ne n)$ which is the required condition I was referring to in my earlier comment.  However (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_sine_and_cosine_series) this only works for odd functions. So you always have to continue your $\cos(x)$ in an odd way (as I did). The luxury, when integrating from $0$ to $\pi/2$, is that this continuation comes implicitely  (cont)

Comment: (cont) so you don't have to actually state what you need to do, in fact you don't need to care about that continuation at all. The question only comes in through the back door if you ask how your series behaves outside of the interval $(0, \pi/2)$, and then the answer is that you actually  have a series of a function which differs from $\cos(x)$ and only coincides with $\cos(x)$  in the interval $(0, \pi/2)$.